# On button click run function and return file

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, amazon-s3

My project shares images and the users are allowed to download X amount of images each month.

Currently I'm able to do both of these functions, but I can't do them at the same time. 
I need to:

1. Return the requested file for download, it's an image so it can't open in new window.
2. Decrement or run a function that captures what image was downloaded.

Currently my view looks like this:

```
@foreach($images as $image)
        <h3 class="panel-title">Image Name</h3>
      <i>{{$image->img_tags}}</i>
          <a class="btn btn-default" href="{{ $image->img_url)}}" download role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span> Download</a>
    @endforeach
```

So it works, it returns the file I want.

But I also want to be able to run this function which is currently in my routes:

```
Route::get('download', function()
{
 DB::table('users')->decrement('downloads', 1);
});
```

I've tried using response::download in my route however since the images are stored on S3 it won't work.

Comment: Did you try including a file name in the response?  So `Response::download($path, $filename);`

Comment: @Azeame I believe response::download only works if the file is hosted locally. I will check, though.